# Making a nav bar revert to normal after scrolling to top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So i'm trying to learn javascript and jQuery. I was coding a project website and wanted to make the nav smaller and transparent as they scroll around the page. i wrote this and it works fine `

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
  $('.nav').css({"opacity": "0.85", "height": "55px"});
  $('.nav-container').css({"margin-top": "-13px", "font-size": "1.4em"})
});
```

`

But i want it to revert back to normal when they scroll all the way to the top. There doesn't seem to be a jQuery event for this.

Comment: can you setup a jsfiddle? it would help us have a visualization on what you want to do.

Comment: I'll do that right now @dunli

Comment: Great! I will try to look at it afterwards :D

Comment: Uh... @Brwski I just read your post again, I guess your problem is you want to know when the user scrolls back to the top right?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BmBeQ/  here it is @dunli, yea i want to revert the css changes once the user reaches the top of the page. Also i just realized my css isn't centering the text in the nav. Anyway to fix that?

Comment: I will look at it. And you can determine if the user scrolls to the top by using `$(window).scrollTop() == 0`

Comment: Ok, so using a if statement i can revert the css back to normal, if that condition is met, right? Going to try it right now.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. :)

Comment: Incidentally, your HTML is invalid: `<li>` elements can *only* be the child-elements of either `<ul>` or `<ol>` elements, *not* `<div>` elements.

Comment: Whoops missed that while i was typing it up :p @DavidThomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally suggest:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    // select the relevant elements:
    $('#nav, .nav-container')[
        // if the window is at the 'top', we use the 'removeClass' method,
        // otherwise we use 'addClass':
        $(window).scrollTop() == 0 ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass'
    // and pass the 'scrolled' class-name to the method:
    ]('scrolled');
});
```

With the CSS:

```
.nav.scrolled {
    opacity: 0.85;
    height: 55px;
}

.nav-container.scrolled {
    margin-top: -13px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BmBeQ/2/).

This also uses corrected (*valid* HTML).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`scroll()`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/).

Comment: Wow, half the lines used as the other answer. I would of never guessed writing it like this. Thanks, very efficient. You get best answer

Comment: May i ask what the ? does?

Comment: You're very welcome indeed! Do be aware that while efficiency is lovely, sometimes readability should win (*I* understand this code, it seems fairly obvious as to what it does, but should others take over your code it might not be so obvious). That's a ternary/conditional operator. It's basically `<assessment condition> ? <if assessment is true> : <if assessment is false>`.

Comment: Yes this is more efficient :)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BmBeQ/1/)

I just changed your `.scroll()` function:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(scroll > 0){
        $('.nav').addClass('scrolled');
        $('.nav-container').addClass('scrolled');
    } else if(scroll == 0){
        $('.nav').removeClass('scrolled');
        $('.nav-container').removeClass('scrolled');
    }
});
```

and added this css:

```
.nav.scrolled {
    opacity:0.85;
    height:55px;
}

.nav-container.scrolled {
    margin-top:-13px;
    font-size:1.4em;
}
```

Comment: Of course! I should of used add class cause than i could just remove it :p. Don't know how this slipped my mind, the .css function just seemed appropriate. Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at at the [Markdown help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/), for guidance on how to format your answer's code. :)

Comment: Hehe, yeah, no problem, and about the centering of texts.. you should add a `ul` element before the `li`. Don't set the height of the `div` or `ul` just play with the `padding` or `height` in the `li`s :D